# Flutter App running smooth on Android but not working on iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

Flutter Version: 2.10.4
App builds successfully for iOS but still not running. Stuck on White Screen!

Android App Running Fine working properly!

Please check screenshot for the warning.

Here are OUTPUT Logs:

```
2022-07-10 03:58:01.349820+0500 Runner[94584:13679909] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-07-10 03:58:01.439358+0500 Runner[94584:13680068] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2022-07-10 03:58:01.457492+0500 Runner[94584:13680063] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2022-07-10 03:58:01.535899+0500 Runner[94584:13680083] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:62629/T_EY6wwk33g=/
2022-07-10 03:58:02.338344+0500 Runner[94584:13680072] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAndroidDeviceInfo on channel plugins.flutter.io/device_info)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:175:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:377:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelDeviceInfo.androidInfo (package:device_info_platform_interface/method_channel/method_channel_device_info.dart:19:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      DeviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo (package:device_info/device_info.dart:25:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      main (package:backyardcart/main.dart:19:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
2022-07-10 03:58:08.587438+0500 Runner[94584:13680061] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C1.1 142.250.76.170:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2022-07-10 03:58:08.587571+0500 Runner[94584:13680061] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C1.1 142.250.76.170:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2022-07-10 03:58:36.998819+0500 Runner[94584:13680174] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C2.1 142.251.42.10:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2022-07-10 03:58:36.998876+0500 Runner[94584:13680174] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C2.1 142.251.42.10:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

Screenshot: [Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR5Jh.jpg)

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

`getAndroidDeviceInfo` is not available for iOS like the exception says. Try something like this:

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Runner project is missing GoogleService-Info.plist. 
if you're sure you've put them inside `ios/Runner`folder, make sure to open Xcode, check inside Runner folder and plist file is referenced.